# Clear filter when there is no text in TextField

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have a textfield which I use to search inside a spesific column. The problem is that after I am done searching and deleted the text from the textfield. The "filter symbol" does not go away?

[image]

I want an simple VBA code that allows me to remove this filter when there is no more text inside the textfield. Here is the code for textfield searching:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
        Sheet1.Range("A2:CM" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & TextBox2.Value & "*"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Sheet1.Range("A2:CM" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & TextBox2.Value & "*"
    If TextBox2.Value = Empty Then Sheet1.Range("A2:CM" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: This is good, is it possible to clear filter only on one column?

Comment: You can clear the filter for columns that you apply the filter.